# Integrating TFS with Sharepoint (ADFS)

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, adfs2.0

I've installed TFS on its own server I would like to create a new SharePoint subsite every time I create a new TFS project. However I'm unable to get TFS to see SharePoint I have from playing about with the admin console for some time.

Previously one I've installed TFS and SharePoint this is worked fine however this time SharePoint if using ADFS forms authentication and I seem unable to to establish connection between the two service.

Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 0):

The TFS "stuff" isn't ADFS aware; what I would suggest is having the default zone run as WIA, that's where TFS would provision.

Then, in SP, extend the Web App to another zone, which would then be setup for AD FS (you didn't say if SP 2010 or the base WSS 3.0).

However, I don't expect TFS explorer, the part that enumerates the SP content store associated with the project to work; however, regular browser based access would work.